# Find the values of $t$ for which the system has unique solution.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to find the values of $t$ for which the system has a unique solution:

$$x+y+tz=1 \\
x+ty+z=1 \\
tx+y+z=-2 $$
I'm not sure if I have to compute the determinant of the coefficient matrix and then find the roots. Would that be enough? Does the $-2$ in the third equation affect the answer in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is enough to compute the determinant. You should find $\;-(t-1)^2(t+2)$, either by row-reduction, or with the *rule of Sarrus*.

It is enough because the set of solutions is an affine subspace, directed by the subvector space of solutions of the associated  *homogeneous* equation,  which is $\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually did the procedure and found that for t=1, -2 the determinant is zero, I just didn't know if that was enough to conclude that for those values the system wouldn't have one unique solution.

Comment: @416256: I've added an explanation in terms of kernel  of the endomorphism associated with the left-hand side and affine subspaces.

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve system of equations simultaneously.

Use the Gaussian Elimination or Gaussian Jordan method to solve it out. A simple example for the case of Gaussian Elimination/Jordan can be found on link

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

It can help out you regarding this method, to apply it for your case.